# JQ Grid Header not changing dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In a jqGrid I have to change header of a column on condition. It should happen when the page is loaded. '`progAccessSearchResults`' is the table id. '`Start Date`' is the column header.
`{name:'startDate', index:'B2B_START_DT', width: 90, resizable: false, hidden : hideStartDate},` is the code for it. While loading the page, if some condition is satisfied, I want to change the header to 'Access Start Date' instead of 'Start Date' . I tried with many examples given in Stackoverflow . But it is not working for me. I tried example like

```
 $(tableId).jqgrid("setLabel", 0, "BBBBB");

 $(tableId).setLabel("ColumnName", "AAAAA");

  $(tableId).jqgrid("setLabel", "ColumnName", "BBBBB");
```

I tried with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            if (#{program.lkpProgType == lookupManager.lkpIdByName('MOVIE') })

            $('#progAccessSearchResults').jqGrid("setLabel", "startDate", "Access Start Date");

        });
```

Inside gridComplete method, I kept

```
if (#{program.lkpProgType == lookupManager.lkpIdByName('MOVIE') })

                            $('#progAccessSearchResults').jqGrid("setLabel", "startDate", "Access Start Date");
```

Nothing worked. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You made typing error I think. `jqgrid` should be changed to `jqGrid`:

```js
$(tableId).jqGrid("setLabel", "startDate", "Access Start Date");
```

The callback `beforeProcessing` could be probably the best place for testing the condition of data returned from the server. You can test some conditions and use `$(this).jqGrid("setLabel", "startDate", someCondition ? "Access Start Date": "Start Date");` to change the column header.

Comment: I added this condition jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if (#{program.lkpProgType == lookupManager.lkpIdByName('MOVIE') })
      
   $('#progAccessSearchResults').jqGrid("setLabel", "startDate", "Access Start Date");
   
   }); But it is not working. Any problem with syntax?

Comment: @Sanjay: The code which you posted looks to me *very suspected* because one can set label **only after the grid is created**. You should place the code on other place. Try to move it directly after creating the grid.

Comment: Inside gridComplete function I added if (#{program.lkpProgType == lookupManager.lkpIdByName('MOVIE') })
      
                   $('#progAccessSearchResults').jqGrid("setLabel", "startDate", "Access Start Date"); Still not working. Really not getting what is happening?

Comment: @Sanjay: What is `#{program.lkpProgType == lookupManager.lkpIdByName('MOVIE') }` ??? You mean probably `if (program.lkpProgType == lookupManager.lkpIdByName('MOVIE')) { ... }`? Just remove any `if` and change the label unconditionally. You will see that the problem which you have is in the wrong `if` condition which you use and not in the `setLabel` method.